# Why is Hibernate expecting a separate table for my composite primary key? (@EmbeddedId)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a leaderboards system as a hobby project. I have three entities:

- `Player` representing a player on the leaderboards
- `StatKey` representing the key of a stat on the leaderboard
- `PlayerStat` representing a particular stat for a given player and should have a composite primary key made up of a `Player` and `StatKey` as well as a foreign key mapping it to the relevant `StatKey` and parent `Player` entities.

I am very overwhelmed by JPA as a whole. And I'm still sort of unsure as to whether or not `@EmbeddedId` vs `@IdClass` is my best bet when creating composite primary keys. From what I had read online, it seemed that the best way is to use `@EmbeddedId`.

However, this results in some very strange queries and table structure. I would've expected three tables:

- player (`pk(id)`, `username`, `total_level`, `total_experience`, `date_created`, `last_updated`)
- player_stat (`pk(player_id, stat_id)`, `level`, `experience`, `date_created`, `last_updated`)
- statkey (`pk(id)`, `key`)

As well as two foreign keys:

- `player_stat` (`player_id`) referencing `player`
- `player_stat` (`stat_id`) referencing `statkey`

All of that gets generated as expected. However, in addition to those three tables, a fourth gets generated:

- `player_stats` (`pk(player_id, stats_player_id, stats_stat_id)`)

As well as the following foreign keys:

- `player_stats` (`stats_player_id`, `stats_stat_id`) referencing `player_stat`
- `player_stats` (`player_id`) referencing `player`

The strange, fourth table is not only a DDL issue, but it is also used when attempting to query the database. I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "player", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "player_uk_username", columnNames = "username"))
public class Player {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "total_level", nullable = false)
    private int totalLevel;

    @Column(name = "total_experience", nullable = false)
    private long totalExperience;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PlayerStat> stats;

    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "last_updated", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime lastUpdated;

    protected Player() {

    }

    public Player(final UUID id, final String username, final Set<PlayerStat> stats) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.stats = stats;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.dateCreated = OffsetDateTime.now();
        this.lastUpdated = this.dateCreated;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.lastUpdated = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "statkey", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "statkey_uk_key", columnNames = "key"))
public class StatKey {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "last_updated", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime lastUpdated;

    protected StatKey() {

    }

    public StatKey(final int id, final String key) {
        this.id = id;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.dateCreated = OffsetDateTime.now();
        this.lastUpdated = this.dateCreated;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.lastUpdated = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class PlayerStatKey implements Serializable {

    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "player")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "player_stat_fk_player_id"))
    private Player player;

    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "stat")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "stat_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "player_stat_fk_statkey_id"))
    private StatKey statKey;

    protected PlayerStatKey() {

    }

    public PlayerStatKey(final Player player, final StatKey statKey) {
        this.player = player;
        this.statKey = statKey;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "player_stat")
public class PlayerStat {

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private PlayerStatKey key;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int level;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int experience;

    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "last_updated", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime lastUpdated;

    protected PlayerStat() {

    }

    public PlayerStat(final PlayerStatKey key, final int level, final int experience) {
        this.key = key;
        this.level = level;
        this.experience = experience;
    }
    

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.dateCreated = OffsetDateTime.now();
        this.lastUpdated = this.dateCreated;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.lastUpdated = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Expected:

```sql
create table player (id binary not null, date_created timestamp not null, last_updated timestamp not null, total_experience bigint not null, total_level integer not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
create table player_stat (date_created timestamp not null, experience integer not null, last_updated timestamp not null, level integer not null, player_id binary not null, stat_id integer not null, primary key (player_id, stat_id))
create table statkey (id integer not null, date_created timestamp not null, key varchar(255) not null, last_updated timestamp not null, primary key (id))
alter table player add constraint player_uk_username unique (username)
alter table statkey add constraint statkey_uk_key unique (key)
alter table player_stat add constraint player_stat_fk_player_id foreign key (player_id) references player
alter table player_stat add constraint player_stat_fk_statkey_id foreign key (stat_id) references statkey
```

Reality:

```sql
create table player (id binary not null, date_created timestamp not null, last_updated timestamp not null, total_experience bigint not null, total_level integer not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
create table player_stat (date_created timestamp not null, experience integer not null, last_updated timestamp not null, level integer not null, player_id binary not null, stat_id integer not null, primary key (player_id, stat_id))
create table player_stats (player_id binary not null, stats_player_id binary not null, stats_stat_id integer not null, primary key (player_id, stats_player_id, stats_stat_id))
create table statkey (id integer not null, date_created timestamp not null, key varchar(255) not null, last_updated timestamp not null, primary key (id))
alter table player add constraint player_uk_username unique (username)
alter table player_stats add constraint UK_9xeo0h5xwn53uq68knp5llr04 unique (stats_player_id, stats_stat_id)
alter table statkey add constraint statkey_uk_key unique (key)
alter table player_stat add constraint player_stat_fk_player_id foreign key (player_id) references player
alter table player_stat add constraint player_stat_fk_statkey_id foreign key (stat_id) references statkey
alter table player_stats add constraint FKrc4tc1jspyawwida0o2dtcp4j foreign key (stats_player_id, stats_stat_id) references player_stat
alter table player_stats add constraint FKfekdv3tvbrd0b8u6c2fuxk5fw foreign key (player_id) references player
```

Comment: Your plan of using a composite primary key for PlayerStat. I do not know whether that's a problem or not, but in general I tend to use a one-dimensional primary key at tables. Yes, the two foreign keys together form a composite key, but imagine the case when you need to add a third foreign key. That would include the complete reorganization of the table if from that point on the first two might get duplicated. Also, if from some point your two foreign keys might get duplicated for any other reason, then you again need to completely reconfigure your table.

Comment: JPA does not know your internal project-related logic, so, from it behavior it seems that it takes a safety-first approach in the creation of a table(pk, fk1, fk2). Why don't you try defining PlayerStat as PlayerStat(pk, fk1, fk2) instead of PlayerStat(fk1, fk2) with (fk1, fk2) being the primary key? If you have a numeric, auto-incremented primary key that's outside the scope of your internal database-related logic, then it would match the table definition JPA so desperately enforces. As a result, maybe the fix is as simple as generating a table in the way JPA generated the additional table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem the issue was the lack of mappings from the parent entities to the child `PlayerStat`.

The solution was to add the following to `StatKey`:

```java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "primaryKey.statKey")
private Set<PlayerStat> stats;
```

As well as add `mappedBy = "primaryKey.player"` to the `@OneToMany` annotation in `Player`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what oa54 said:

1. This has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA. If you have the SQL generated automatically, I assume you (accidentally) use the SQL generation feature of your JPA provider, likely Hibernate. I'll update the question title accordingly.
2. I'd highly recommend to rather use a dedicated SQL migration tool (Flyway or Liquibase) to write the SQL defining your data structures as you will have to resort to something like this at some point anywa. Once your classes need new fields, you need to migrate data, alter tables instead of recreating them etc.

Comment: Appreciate it! Also, for what it's worth, while I definitely do agree about #2, in this case, the weird generation was also reflected in the queries it was making (i.e. it was expecting and required the additional table in order to function).